# freeRTOS scheduling configurations for tasks

Tags: scheduling, xilinx, freertos

I have my freeRTOS currently working on my Microzed board. I am using the Xilinx SDK as the software platform and until now I have been able to create tasks and assign priority.

I was just curious to know if it would be possible to assign a fixed time for each of my tasks such that for example after 100 miliseconds my scheduler would switch to the next task . So is it possible to set a fixed execution time for each of my tasks ?? As far as I checked I could not find a method to work this out, if there is any means to implement this using the utilities of freeRTOS, kindly let me know guys.

Answer (score 2):

By default FreeRTOS will time slice tasks of equal priority, see http://www.freertos.org/a00110.html#configUSE_TIME_SLICING, but there is nothing to guarantee that each task gets an equal share of the CPU.  For example, interrupts use an unknown amount of processing time during each time slice, and higher priority tasks can use part or all of a time slice.

Question for you though - why would you want the behaviour you requested?  Maybe if you said what you were trying to achieve, rather than than ask if a feature existed, people would be able to make helpful suggestions.